# Number of records shows correctly except column 'New Computed Start Date' shows all '######' format when date is pretty old date, example: 01-DEC-1184

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

In disco and ssrs Number of records shows correctly except column 'New Computed Start Date' shows all '######' format when date is pretty old date, example: 01-DEC-1184 but when export data from ssrs  .

when export data from ssrs [image]

data in ssrs before exporting[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you open an excel and input several dates in cells, any date before 01-01-1900 won't be parsed as date (if you set cell formatting to date for those cells). You can check this link for more details: http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/earlydates.htm

Same should apply for your data in the SSRS report.
I would format that column as text in SSRS instead as date.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this 3 steps to display the date correctly and transfer it correctly to Excel:

1. Go to your general report settings and set the language (this value cant be empty)
2. Go to your textbox properties and set the `Number` format to `Date`
3. Go to your textbox expression and add a `CDate()` around your field `=CDate(Fields!YourDate.Value)`

This way the date gets displayed and exported correctly.